# How does Python PEP 0484's typing module coexist with previous versions?

Tags: python, type-hinting

The PEP talks about how type-hinted code can be run in previous versions of Python, but if I import the `typing` module, how can that work? I can't find the answer in the PEP.

I maintain a large codebase where the same code runs in Python 2.5+ and 3.x. I'd like to add type hints but don't see how this can work.

Answer (score 0):

Just found what I think is the answer: the module is available on PyPI:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing/3.5.0